# Edmonds' maximum cardinality matching in Boost Graph Library running forever?

Tags: c++, boost

I don't see anywhere in the documentation that mentions the word "stuck" or "infinite" : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph/doc/maximum_matching.html

On a few graphs, the algorithm runs for a very long time. The example where the function loops forever (it seems) are quite large so I don't know how to post them here...

I just call the function like so :

```
boost::edmonds_maximum_cardinality_matching(G,
    boost::make_iterator_property_map(mate_map.begin(), boost::get(boost::vertex_index, G)));
```

Where G is a graph and mate_map is a vector of vertex descriptor.

EDIT: I forgot to include the most important bit

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> graph;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using directed graph may lead to infinite looping.

Use

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> graph;
```

Undirected graph instead.